# How to customise UIActivityViewController to my selected apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have customised UIActivityViewController as possible from my side. I have excluded all items from it as listed below:-

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[videoURL] applicationActivities:nil];  
controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                         UIActivityTypeMail,
                                         UIActivityTypePrint,
                                         UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                         UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                         UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                         UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                         UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                         UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                         UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                         UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                         UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks,
                                         @"com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension",
                                         @"com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now I only want to show **Message, Facebook, Instagram, and WhatsApp** in the ActivityController.

**1-** How can I exclude all other installed app from list to show only above mentioned apps?

**2-** I also wants to exclude 'Add to iCloud Drive' from list.

**Note:** I have already tried customised action sheet and able to share image only with it. But I want to share video in above mentioned apps. And they are not providing any way to share video.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Attachments after my code execution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use customize action sheet

Comment: Then you should use your custom action sheet

Comment: I have tried customised action sheet and able to share image only with it. But I want to share video in above mentioned apps. And they are not providing any way to share video. Please suggest.